# NetworkManager.SIngleton.StopHost(); give an erorr

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm tying to create multiplayer game on unity 2021.2.8f1 and when I'm calling NetworkManager.Singleton.StopHost();
I'm geting the next erorr:
Assets\scrips\multiplayers\MainMenu\MainMenu.cs(151,42): error CS1061: 'NetworkManager' does not contain a definition for 'StopHost' and no accessible extension method 'StopHost' accepting a first argument of type 'NetworkManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
the same happens when I'm calling
NetworkManager.Singleton.StopClient();
befor that in the script I'm calling
NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
and is doing fine
Here's my code*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Unity.Netcode;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace DapperDino.UMT.ConnectionApproval
{
    public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Password;

        public TMP_InputField NameGameObject;
        public TMP_InputField PasswordGameObject;

        public GameObject mainMenu;
        public GameObject AboutMenu;

        public GameObject UIMenu;

        private void Start()
        {
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnServerStarted += HeandelServerStarted;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += HeandleClientConnected;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += HeandleClientDisconnect;
        }
        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (NetworkManager.Singleton == null) { return; }
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnServerStarted -= HeandelServerStarted;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback -= HeandleClientConnected;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback -= HeandleClientDisconnect;
        }

        public int CheckPasswordAndName()
        {
            if (Password != null || Password != "")
            {
                if (Name != null || Name != "")
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else { return 1; }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Name == null || Name == "") { return 2; }
                return 3;
            }
        }
        private void HeandelServerStarted()
        {
            if (NetworkManager.Singleton.IsHost)
            {
                HeandleClientConnected(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
            }
        }
        private void HeandleClientConnected(ulong clientID)
        {
            if (clientID == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId)
            {
                UIMenu.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        private void HeandleClientDisconnect(ulong clientID)
        {
            if (clientID == NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId)
            {
                UIMenu.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        private void ApprovalCheck(byte[] connectionDate, ulong clientID, NetworkManager.ConnectionApprovedDelegate callback)
        {
            string password = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connectionDate);
            bool approveConnection = password == this.Password;
            callback(true, null, approveConnection, null, null);
        }

        public void Host()
        {
            if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 0)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectionApprovalCallback += this.ApprovalCheck;
                NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
            }
            else
            {
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 1) { }
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 2) { }
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 3) { }
            }
        }

        public void Join()
        {
            if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 0)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.NetworkConfig.ConnectionData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Password);
                NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
            }
            else
            {
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 1) { }
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 2) { }
                if (CheckPasswordAndName() == 3) { }
            }
        }

        public void SetName()
        {
            Name = NameGameObject.text;
        }

        public void SetPassword()
        {
            Password = PasswordGameObject.text;
        }
        void Update()
        {
            SetName();
            SetPassword();
        }

        public void Quit()
        {

        }

        public void About()
        {
            mainMenu.SetActive(false);
            AboutMenu.SetActive(true);
        }

        public void back()
        {
            mainMenu.SetActive(true);
            AboutMenu.SetActive(false);
        }

        public void Leave()
        {
            if (NetworkManager.Singleton.IsHost)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.StopHost();
                NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectionApprovalCallback -= ApprovalCheck;
            }
            else if(NetworkManager.Singleton.IsClient)
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.StopClient();
            }
            UIMenu.SetActive(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ruzihm in UNet it would be `singleton` with lowercase as to Unity naming conventions .. same in Mirror so it seems OP is using another library ...?

Comment: Singleton with lowercase is giving anther error, Unity can not find singleton
do I need to from import another place, and if I do from where?

Comment: @derHugo My reading comprehension is in shambles. lol ;)

Comment: @derHugo Once again the new generation of Unity documentation has failed. See my answer below. I also upvoted this post because it actually helped me understand where the confusion came from.

Comment: @Ruzihm to be fair it seems to still be in pre-release state ^^ funny though that it is already "the" recommended library anyway

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.0.0, [NetCode's NetworkManager](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager) no longer contains methods called `StopClient` or `StopHost`.

At time of writing, the documentation for `NetworkManager` has not been updated to reflect this change so gives incorrect advice about how to disconnect. A [fix for the documentation has been contributed](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.multiplayer.docs/pull/482) but has not yet been merged.

Anyway, with version 1.0.0 you should simply use [`NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();`](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager#shutdown) in all cases.